# How to vlookup with multiple if/or parameters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The goal is to write a formula asking:

**Pseudo Code:**
'insert in column e':

`if cell in column d is in column a then 1, if cell is in column b then 2, if cell is in column c then 3`.

**First Attempt**
I have a way to get up to 2 if statements with this formula:
`=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B2,cell_range,0),"1",),"2")`;

But I'd super like to add in a 3rd 'value_if' clause.

**Screenshot**:

[image]

Comment: you can replace "2" in your formula with another if

Comment: This is actually what I did - when it comes to really long excel formulas, I shy away but that guidance was perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE put in E2 and copy/drag down:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$2:$C$12)/($A$2:$C$12 = D2),1)
```

[image]

Comment: btw, can you make that COUNTIFS solution for [COUNTIF > 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691953) an answer? (I got ms to pull the documetation sometime this week)

Comment: @Jeeped you want me to make that an answer?

Comment: Yeah, it's as good or better that full-column sumproduct that ms told me was the correct answer. I found it innovative.

Comment: This certainly works as well - ran into an issue though when implementing to my actual sheet where the formula was spitting out 4, 5 and 6s rather than 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Then your data is columns D:F.  you can simply subtract 3, as the formula returns the actual column.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=countif(a:a, d2)+countif(b:b, d2)*2+countif(c:c, d2)*3  'mutliples
=sign(countif(a:a, d2))+sign(countif(b:b, d2))*2+sign(countif(c:c, d2))*3  'singles
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this into E2 and copy down as well:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$12,0)) = FALSE, 1,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D2,$B$2:$B$12,0)) = FALSE,2,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D2,$C$2:$C$12,0)) = FALSE,3,"Nothing Found")))
```