# Length Issues when using Countif or Vlookup

Tags: excel

I have a column that I am trying to do an easy COUNTIF on... I am looking to see how many times each value appears in the column. It works fine for 90% of my data, but for a few values (seem to be the longer ones). I've also tried VLOOKUPs and have had the same issue.

I deleted half of the longer version and it worked... How do I get around the length issue?

```
9   ||   Missouri Sowthwast Oregon LOcation Template regions to enhance boise next steps left and right websites sharing and relationships across all 
#VALUE!   ||   Regional-led training for all of our people (led by the our regional leaders) that promotes the usage of the brand new technology pizza and pasta, left, reungdjsf and allows how the new organization with work toeghers (i.e., how will best we partner practices be collected and shared across D&C next time)
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688846/identify-duplicates-or-countif-255-characters-long-text

Comment: And: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691953/trouble-with-recommended-work-around-for-countif-255-characters