# Excel, get arround the limit of CountIf()

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

so I have an Excel Worksheet with the Mail-Addresses of all resposible persons for the specific items. Some people appear more than once, but when I try `=COUNTIF(A2:A9999;A2)` and then copy it down, I get the error `#VALUE!`.

I looked it up, and there is a character limit of 255. I used `=LEN(A2)` to find out how long the cells were, and they get up to a length of 1500 chars.

Is there still a way to get around that limit, or something else?

Thanks for the help.

Kind regards
Elias

Comment: What about an absolute reference: COUNTIF(A$2:A$9999;A2) ?

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, I am not sure, whether, `LEFT()` Function or any Function works for the range part in `COUNTIF()` or `COUNTIFS()` as shown in answers. ?

Comment: @Elias why did you tag vga? what is that ?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya don't see any left() in what I typed...

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, i am not talking about yours the one shown in answers.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya so did you test it? I won't because I think you would need something with indirect and it is not the range, but the contents...

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, I tested, Excel wont allow to use any function for the range part in any IF's family i believe

Comment: Worth looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51733653/4961700

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT` does not have that limitation.  And you really have mail addresses with a length of 1500 characters?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I donßt know if there is a workaround with VGA, so I wanted to make sure. @RonRosenfeld No the Addresses are not 1500 chars long, but there are differernt addresses in a cell. Up to 20 I believe, and those sum up to 1500 characters. The adresses are splitted by a `;`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two problems: you are dragging down the formula `F(A2:A9999,A2)` (which causes the formula to modify into `F(A3:A10000,A3)`, `F(A4:A10001,A4)`, ... while you are interested in `F(A2:A9999,Ax)` for every `x`. As indicated by Solar Mike, you can solve this using `F(A$2:A$9999,Ax)`.

Next you have the problem with the `Countif()` limitation. There already is the proposal to shorten your string, e.g. by using `LEFT(range,225)` but I believe the first thing you should be looking for, is the uniqueness of your data: you are saying that your data are e-mail addresses. Are those e-mail addresses of different companies (which would mean that it might be useful to check the `RIGHT()` part instead of the `LEFT()` part?

I would advise you to check those really large addresses (1500 characters long? I've never seen such a long address), try to shorten them and use your `CountIf()` function on those shortened e-mail addresses.

Comment: No, I don´t have such a long address, but there is anything from 1 to 20 different addresses in one cell. Thats why I have up to 1500 characters. And yes, all those addresses are from up to 10 differner companies, and not even the stuff before the "@" is structured te same way. The addresses are sapperated by a `;`. could I spitt them by this and then count them?